# Project has been deleted/replaced

Tags: git, android-studio

When I opened my project I saw that android-studio started downloading some gradle packages and in terminal there was printed out:`** Message: Remote error from secret service: org.freedesktop.Secret.Error.IsLocked: Cannot create an item in a locked collection
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.0-bin.zip
................................................................
Unzipping /root/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.0-bin/3p92xsbhik5vmig8i90n16yxc/gradle-4.0-bin.zip to /root/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.0-bin/3p92xsbhik5vmig8i90n16yxc
Set executable permissions for: /root/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.0-bin/3p92xsbhik5vmig8i90n16yxc/gradle-4.0/bin/gradle`

When android studio finished downloading I could see no longer my project, instead of this catalog hierarchy containing and saying me nothing:
[image]

and that information about not a gradle project...

Do you have any ideas what have I could done wrong?

Ohh, I was uploading it to Git, but it didn't success and maybe there was an option about deleting local files that was checked and I didn't uncheck this. If I did this, how can I restore my project?

Answer (score 1):

There is a good chance that you have done nothing wrong, and it's just Intellij / Android Studio that deleted your files. I had a similar issue, and it is a known bug, consider reporting it here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206877445-Please-help-IntelliJ-11-just-deleted-all-my-files-

Moving on to recovering your files.

1. Run `git log` and see if the commit is still there. If you can see it, run `git reset --hard <The hash of the commit>`
2. Use a program like *recuva* to `undelete` your files. In my case I hadn't added files to git, but luckily I was working on a different partition and the deleted files weren't overwritten. *recuva* saved my progress.

Comment: wooow it's so weird. Next time I'll take more care to make copies more often. Thanks for info, I'm trying to recover my progress. Luckilly it was just 8h of work so not so much.